# PHP AES encryption - cannot decrypt some of the values stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I'm using http://www.phpaes.com/ to encrypt some values and store them in a MySQL database. The column type for the database is VARBINARY(512) which is the only one that seemed to work.

The values (plain text) are strings not longer than 128 chars but as this is my first take on something more serious than plain md5 or such I do think I'm doing something very bad here. First of all, the initialization vector is always the same, but this really isn't a concern for this project.

Problem is, when I decrypt the values, some values come out ok while other's not. Any idea what could the problem be here?

I'm using OFB cypher mode, 256 bit key and the values are email addresses and phone numbers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *which is the only one that seemed to work* - This is not a good thing to say when talking about encrypted data.

Comment: Not very helpful, are you? It's not a good thing to say about anything, but when you have to get up to speed with something you haven't used before in just a few hours you're kind of left out of options.

Comment: First, encryption is not hashing, so MD5 is not equivalent to AES, since MD5 is meant to be one-way. When you encrypt a block of some data, you have to be confident you understand how that encryption works, otherwise, retrieving a block data or message out of the encrypted text will be difficult or troublesome to say the least. You first should have a very firm grasp of how your process is working, hence my original comment. The amount of time available is irrelevant.

Comment: Note, I'm not trying to be rude or otherwise, I'm just stating something that needs to be said, mainly that you need to first understand your encryption process. Note, also, that you included no code or other information except a textual description.

Comment: Jared, you are. Also, time is always relevant.

Re code, I don't think it's necessary as everything is explained above. If you do think code is relevant you can let me know what exactly you need to know. It's nothing more than an insert statement  and the value is the encrypted result from the PHP AES class mentioned above. As I said, everything worked fine with the values I tested with - for some values it doesn't. Obviously, I wouldn't have any idea what those values are now.

Comment: Right. You don't state why a certain field type "seems to be the only one that works", nor do you provide any demonstration code showing how you're working with the data and where it may be going wrong, yet now I somehow have to *specifically* ask for the code to answer *your* problem? Ha ha.

Comment: Oh man... No need to flame. If you don't want to help, that's cool, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You have to change the column type to `BLOB`. If that doesn't work, try trimming your strings or data or whatever.

Also, MySQL comes with AES functionality. Did you consider that?

Comment: @Claudiu - Trimming the strings would help in the sense that it would "normalize" your string so you wouldn't have leading/trailing (interposed?) whitespace. I would just point out that if you're having the results fail somewhat randomly in this way, that using AES to do checksum/digital signatures may not be the best approach to "encrypting" the data in the first place if you just want to validate a match, instead of reverse it to plaintext.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Well said. I always trim my strings, and the built-in MySQL AES functions give me less trouble than PHP functions.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct as I had no idea about the trimming. I was doing that as part of the validation. Everything was actually fine but I had some values that weren't actually encrypted but had the value 'hidden' - Long story, client request. 

Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Just saw your reply, thanks. That makes sense and its helpful. I actually need the data encrypted as it's sensitive user information - emails and phone numbers. Apparently everything was ok. I was thinking about MySQL's built in function but due to other factors I might need to migrate this over to another environment and I didn't want to have any dependencies other than PHP.

Comment: @Claudiu - No worries, I probably came off like a dick in my previous comments, which wasn't intentional. If you're trying to match a value (validate against a signature), that's not technically encryption, vs hashing, which is a calculation against a value, you have to be very careful about the input. If the client requires you to use a certain methodology to match a value and that methodology is an encryption (as opposed to a hashing) methodology, then you need to be very careful you don't allow any characters you're not expecting, otherwise you may have unexpected results.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No worries, I wasn't in a very good mood either, wouldn't have reacted like that otherwise. As for the md5 comparison, that was a mistake from my side - isn't md5 a one-way encryption? Only use it for passwords and such. This time I actually have to decrypt the data. 

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Claudiu - Yes, MD5 (and SHA1, and SHA256, et al) are one-way, not meant to decrypt the values functions. If you need to store a value in a way that others wouldn't easily be able to understand the original value, while still allowing you to derive the original value, that's encryption. Encryption is often used for "message" encryption, which doesn't care about whitespace so much, but if you need a value to be parseable/matchable after decryption, you need to first find a way to (without stripping real data) derive a base value, such as removing whitespace and other characters potentially.

Comment: I personally use SHA-512, as it returns a longer string and uses a stronger algorithm, but thats just me.